# error: package javax.servlet does not exist/ directory not found

Tags: servlets, javac

```
tomcat
 -webapps
    -Servlet
       -WEB-INF
           -lib
           -classes
              -cc
                -openhome
                    -HelloServlet.java
```

in cmd , 
`C:\tomcat\webapps\Servlet>javac -classpath .;c:\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar -d ..\classes\cc\openhome\HelloServlet.java`

but message says `directory not found`

and I compile the `HelloServlet.java` , it shows  package `javax.servlet` does not exist

I tried each method found from here, is anyone know what it happens?  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-d` is the switch for changing output directory and not for defining a java source file and it expects a directory, not a file.

Also that `class` folder is usually for the compiled classes and not for the sources.

Try this:

```
 javac -classpath .;c:\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar -d .\WEB-INF\classes .\WEB-INF\classes\cc\openhome\HelloServlet.java
```

Comment: Hi Balint , what do you mean ?? I don't get it ? so how do i fix it ?

Comment: Is the `c:\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar`file there by the way?

Comment: javac: file not found: ..\classes\cc\openhome\HelloServlet.java

Comment: I changed the location of HelloServlet.java , I put it under the WEB-INF folder

Comment: Fix the relative path to the file, if you move it. `javac -classpath .;c:\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar -d .\WEB-INF\classes .\WEB-INF\HelloServlet.java` if it is in the WEB-INF.